# Dynamic Menu generation using webservices

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, menu, orchardcms

I have a website which generates the navigation menus based on the user access levels. The code uses webservices & xslt to get the data and transform it in the browser.

Now I want to export this site to a freely available CMS, Can anyone suggest a CMS in which this functionality is built-in. I really liked Orchard but am Unable to get this to work.

Thank you all for your time and the suggestions.

Comment: I don't know any that have it built in, but can't you just extend Orchard and add on your custom functionality?

Comment: I think that's a valid and doable thing. am already working on it. this question is kinda lame.. thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you won't find any CMS that would have something like this built-in and wouldn't involve some coding to make it work.

**It would be fairly easy to add such functionality in Orchard, though**. The only two things you'd have to do would be:

1. Create an [Orchard module](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Building-a-hello-world-module.ashx) (which can be autogenerated [via command-line](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Command-line-scaffolding.ashx))
2. Create a class in your module project that implements **INavigationProvider** interface. There is only a single method to override that returns the menu items collection (properly hierarchized via *Parent <-> Items* properties). All the custom item-retrieval logic should happen right here. There is also a *MenuName* property to override - this should return the name of a generated menu (can be pretty much anything).

And basically that is all - compile the solution and enable your module feature via *Dashboard -> Modules -> Features*.

To display the menu you could use the **[Advanced Menu](http://www.orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Menu)** module. After installing and enabling this feature you can drop the MenuWidget (or StyledMenuWidget if you want a simple, pre-styled menu) to any Zone you want (you can do it from *Dashboard -> Widgets*). When doing that you'd be asked for the name of the menu to render. **Provide the name your INavigationProvider's MenuName property returns.**

HTH